# Django dumpdata generates invalid json format file

Tags: json, django, database, python-3.x

I'm working Django1.11. and I want to move from sqlite to PostgreSQL. So I need to dump data from Sqlite and load to PostgreSQL.
I generate the dumped data with

```
python3 manage.py dumpdata > db.json
```

I have changed db setting to PostgreSQL and did

```
python3 manage.py loaddata db.json
```

and got this error.

```
raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None

json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

So I use `hexdump` and tried.

```
raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None

django.core.serializers.base.DeserializationError: Problem installing fixture '/var/lib/myproject/fixtures/db.json': Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

I took the look at  `db.json` and it is not valid json.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm working on linux.The problem was that at the head of the `db.json`,the sentence "trying windows paths instead" is attached and highlighted.
When I open the file using `vi command`, I thought it's not part of the file. But it is the part of the file. I just manually deleted this sentence. It worked. But finally I didn't use `python loaddata` for database migration. You may have many errors if you use pyhton functions. So I quitted do it on the Django built-in function and used `pgloader`. It's easy way with no errors.

Comment: Similar case here, but the nefarious text was a line printed by my Django project's `settings.py`. Anything that Django prints to `stdout` will invariably end up being written to the head of the file before the JSON output.

Comment: Yup @CameronHyde i had exactly the same issue, a print statement executed in an arbitrary python module (`admin.py` for me). I skipped my first line with `tail -n +2 db.json > db_cleaned.json`